# The process cannot be accessed because it's being used by another process

Tags: c#

Allow me to paint the picture if you will. All the posts I have read regarding this issue the only thing  i haven't found is the solution/cause to the problem. Why hasn't MS fixed this?

I work on a solution at home and at work and we have Team Foundation Server(TFS) setup. When at home I have to VPN in. I have VS 2010 SP1, Win XP SP3 at work and Win 7 64 bit at home w/ SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer.

For years now I have worked with no issues while debugging what so ever from either location.

Just recently we published the application to the server from the work location (Win XP SP3 Pro) and only since then I get this 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error.

I do not have any problems working from home. (WIn 7 64 bit machine) and I have not published from home at all either for what it's worth.

When at work I have to restart VS or keep task manager open and endprocess for the process of the app named **appname_vshost.exe** (or simular) 2-3 times before debug will run again smoothly. If I don't VS IDE is very painfully slow to respond.

I have totally deleted the Project files locally and retrieved them fresh from the TFS.
Everything runs fine until I edit something in the solution (project) and it starts all over again.

Anyone know of any solutions that I may not have found as yet?
I think having to creat a "work around" is a bandaid and not a solition any ideas?

Comment: Do you use any custom controls?

Comment: You say "I get this 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error."  *When* do you get that error?  When you start debugging, when an error happens, when you launch the app...?

Comment: Try turning off "Project Properties" > "Debug" > "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process". That always works for me.

Comment: I did what John said here and it worked. Any idea why that caused it after publishing? Is this a VS sercurity related thing? Our IT people are looking at it but it is not their area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean when you compile....

I wasted days upon days upon days on this...until I come across this:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/700166/compiler-locks-generated-exe-file-when-application-experience-service-is-turned-off

It is essentially due to the Application Experience services being turned off.

Go into your Services list (Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services), ensure it is set to Automatic.

Not had the problem since.

Comment: Odd, several posts about it being turned *on* causing the problem.  It certainly looks implicated though.  Turning it off requires some magic: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902196

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Unlocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlocker) to determine which file exactly is beeing locked by which process, you can run it on folder level so you may try it once the error occurs on the entire project filder.

Comment: Thanks for the replies all. What troubles me is that I had no problems until I published from VS on the Win XP machine at work. Yes Dan, I will get the error when I try to go into debug or as soon as I modify a control or code and try to debug.